# Is there a way to get multiple parameters back from an interop call in nanoFramework

Tags: c#, interop, nanoframework

I am trying to get multiple parameters from a struct in a single interop call. The struct in question has the following signature:

```c
struct struct_name
{
    uint16_t param0;
    uint8_t param1;
    uint8_t param2;
    uint8_t *param3;
};
```

and I am trying to get all of these parameters into managed c# code.

Comment: Have you read the [information on marshalling structs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/marshalling-classes-structures-and-unions#structures-sample)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's an "advanced" usage scenario that's not supported currently. Only base CLR types can be used in Interop. You have to have those as individual params passed with ref.

Comment: I tried this but the stubs that got generated had incorrect/no types.

Comment: Something else wrong then...
Care to join the project Discord server for a more interactive support?